# String.equalsIgnoreCase, but for characters

Tags: java

PLEASE do not mark this as a duplicate. I have already looked at the other one and it is NOT what I am looking for.

Is there an efficient API to do the same as String.equalsIgnoreCase, but for characters instead? I have a method to return how many occurrences there are of a single character in a string, but I realized it will only search for the case of what you type.

```
public int numTimes(char what) {
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < quote.length(); i++) {
        if (quote.charAt(i) == what)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: If the duplicate is not what you are looking for, please explain _why_ not. You seem to be looking for a way to compare two characters, ignoring the case of those characters, which is what the duplicate is about.

Comment: The duplicate is an issue of converting over language (Turkish) and making sure it's still giving the same answer.

Comment: No, it's about comparing characters ignoring the case. Change `if (quote.charAt(i) == what)` to `if (Character.toLowerCase(quote.charAt(i)) == Character.toLowerCase(what))`.

Comment: Could we be looking at different questions. You answer is what I was looking for--it is not what I was seeing on the suggested duplicate. Regardless, thank you!

Comment: @ShawnBenson, please explain technically why this is not a duplicate of the question above ? Why is it not what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to convert the character, regardless of initial case, to lower (or upper for that matter) case and then compare.

Use:

```
Character.toLowerCase(quote.charAt(i)) == what
```